# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _imp_curl_easy_init referenced in fanction _main

Tags: c++, curl

Здраствуйте, я не могу скомпилировать нормально код для быиблиотеки curl-7.63.

```
    Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_init referenced in function _main   test    C:\Users\Max\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test\test\main.obj   1   
    Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_setopt referenced in function _main test    C:\Users\Max\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test\test\main.obj   1   
    Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_perform referenced in function _main    test    C:\Users\Max\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test\test\main.obj   1   
    Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_cleanup referenced in function _main    test    C:\Users\Max\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test\test\main.obj   1   
    Warning LNK4272 library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86' test    C:\curl\lib\Debug\libcurl-d.lib 1   
    Error   LNK1120 4 unresolved externals  test    C:\Users\Max\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test\Debug\test.exe  1
```

Удаляю полнсть код и оставляю только классы все компилирует.
Использую VS 2015. Компилировал библиотеку с помощю инструментов VS 2015.

Пример кода:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <curl/curl.h>
    //главная функция
    int main(void)
    {
        //уже знакомый объект CURL
        CURL *curl;
        //объект - результат вызова функции curl_easy_perform
        CURLcode res;
        //выполняем инициализацю
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl) { //проверяем
                    //задаем опцию - получить страницу по адресу http://google.com
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "google.com");
            //указываем прокси сервер
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "proxy:8080");
            //задаем опцию отображение заголовка страницы
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            //вызываем функцию, выполняющюю все операции, заданные в опциях (получение страницы, передача данных и т.д.), результат - объект типа CURLcode
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            //выполняем обязательное завершение сессии    
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'` - капитан нужен?

Comment: при удалении кода до классов, все работает